# truffle debugger throws error

Tags: truffle

I run `truffle test`

and see my transaction in ganache:

```
 Transaction: 0x2e9aab59f190743cc740b6f4de9963354386fde246287fc383688f1e055e4451
  Gas usage: 137228
  Block Number: 92
  Block Time: Mon Jun 04 2018 11:12:12 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

when I run `truffle debug 0x2e9aab59f190743cc740b6f4de9963354386fde246287fc383688f1e055e4451`

I get :

```
redux-saga error: uncaught at session.saga
at session.saga 
 at recordInstance 
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'context' of null
```

My versions are:

```
Truffle v4.1.11 (core: 4.1.11)
Solidity v0.4.24 (solc-js)
```

Any idea what I can do to get this working? 
Thanks